# how to implement more than 5 bands equalizer on android?

Tags: android, equalizer

hello~ everybody!

I would like to implement equalizer on android. There is one issue that android is only providing 5 bands(the result of Equalizer.getNumberOfBands()) but I want more than 5.

Could you please let me know how to do this?

or does anybody know where I could get open source library for the equalizer?

Please help me~

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/sasken-player/

I used this to get the 10 band euqalizer. In the native jni code in equalizer class, there is ppf.c file where you can configure your various kind of filter requirements.

Other than that I can find anything else online yet.

Comment: cannot get it work with latest android studio and gradle, I set `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` but it still gives some errors